# Restore RavenDB backup

Tags: ravendb, database-restore, ravendb-studio

i'm trying to restore RavenDB from it's back up file, i write this query

```
Raven.Server.exe -src 'D:\documents\RavenDB\RavenDB' -dest TestRavenDB -restore
```

but it's not restoring database from the back up file, some one have any idea to restoring RavenDB from backup file.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or other output from that command?

Comment: it's not giving any error, just alerting me database already exist, while i've deleted it from RavenDB and from disk

Comment: i also tried RavenDB web console but couldn't get succeed.

Comment: what happens if you give non-existing folder as a destination?

Comment: it didn't give me any error but not doing what i want...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of RavenDB you are using, but here is the command to restore a RavenDB database in RavenDB 3.5.

Raven.Server.exe --restore-source=[backup location] --restore-database=[URL to destination server]

from https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/server/administration/backup-and-restore

Note is that the --restore-database=[URL to destination server] allows you to run the command from a different machine than the server (like a developer workstation with RavenDB server installed). However, the --restore-source=[backup location] is relative to the server. So, when you say d:\documents\RavenDB\RavenDB would be the D: drive of the server.

Also, you said that you deleted the database and the files. When I deleted the database, but not the files (the default in version 3.5), I received a non-obvious error and stacktrace.

Hope that helps. Sorry I could not be more specific as to your problem.